# JQuery get returning error when using read me later api

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I have the following code which hits the [text](http://readitlaterlist.com/api/docs/#text) method of the [read it later api](http://readitlaterlist.com/api/docs/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var request = $.get('https://text.readitlaterlist.com/v2/text?apikey=KEY&url=http://readitlaterlist.com/api/docs');
});
```

*Where KEY is my api key*

If I use the same API key with http://web-sniffer.net/ and perform a get it works correctly. Why is my jQuery get returning an error?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do a GET from the client (with JS) due to XSS browser policies, you will need to access this resource from your server.